# Multiplication Tables in Python

Tags: python

this is my code right now:

```
loop_count = 1
for i in range(mystery_int):
    for x in range(1,mystery_int):
        print(x*loop_count, end=" ")
    print (loop_count)
    loop_count+=1
```

this is what it is supposed to print:

```
1   2   3   4   5
2   4   6   8   10
3   6   9   12  15
4   8   12  16  20
5   10  15  20  25
```

But it prints:

```
1 2 3 4 1
2 4 6 8 2
3 6 9 12 3
4 8 12 16 4
5 10 15 20 5
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to `range` till `mystery_int + 1` because in `range`, second argument is exclusive. So, for example, `range(1,6)` gives numbers from 1 to 5.

Also, I added an empty `print()` which basically adds a newline to match with desired output.
Using `end='\t'` further aligns output properly.

```
loop_count = 1
mystery_int = 5

for i in range(mystery_int):
    for x in range(1, mystery_int + 1):
        print(x * loop_count, end='\t')
    print()
    loop_count += 1
```

Comment: You should also explain why you use the empty call to the print function as it deviates from his original post

Comment: Nothing on the spacing of the desired output?

Comment: You can replace `end=" "` with `end="\t"` to match the output.

Answer (score 0):

the range for `x` should be `range(1,mystery_int+1)`, and you also incorrectly print `loop_count` at the end of each line (which I replaced with the empty string, just to produce a  newline).

```
loop_count = 1
for i in range(mystery_int):
    for x in range(1,mystery_int+1):
        print(x*loop_count, end=" ")
    print('')
    loop_count+=1
```

Note that the `loop_count` variable is not really needed. You could write the program as:

```
for i in range(1,mystery_int+1):
    for x in range(1,mystery_int+1):
        print(x*i, end=" ")
    print('')
```

or even better as:

```
for i in range(1,mystery_int+1):
    print(*[x*i for x in range(1,mystery_int+1)], sep=" ")
```

Answer (score -1):

you are running on two for loops in addition to using another counter, i would recommend sticking only to the loops:

```
for i in range(1,mystery_int+1):
    for x in range(1,mystery_int+1):
        print(i*x, end=" ")
    print("") # new line
```